# CSS: Box border is not shrinking when the screen width becomes smaller

Tags: html, css

I am working on a HTML/CSS page which displays a column of div boxes and I have the following code:

request.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Requests Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="requestnew.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="requests-page">
        <h1>Requests</h1>
        <div class="requests-container">
            <div class="request-list">
                <div class="request-box">
                    <div class="request-details">
                        <div>
                            <h1>Table 9, 12:00PM</h1>
                            <h2>Need help with ordering</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="status-button">
                            <button type="button" class="request-button">Assistance Requested</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="request-box">
                    <div class="request-details">
                        <div>
                            <h1>Table 9, 12:00PM</h1>
                            <h2>Need help with ordering</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="status-button">
                            <button type="button" class="request-button">Assistance Requested</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="request-box">
                    <div class="request-details">
                        <div>
                            <h1>Table 9, 12:00PM</h1>
                            <h2>Need help with ordering</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="status-button">
                            <button type="button" class="request-button">Assistance Requested</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="request-box">
                    <div class="request-details">
                        <div>
                            <h1>Table 9, 12:00PM</h1>
                            <h2>Need help with ordering</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="status-button">
                            <button type="button" class="request-button">Assistance Requested</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

request.css:

```
.requests-container {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    grid-row-gap: 30px;
}

.request-box {
    border: 1px solid #c3c9c8;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #ededed;
    margin: 10px;
}

.request-details {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0 30px;
    height: 100%;
}

.request-details h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #28bfa6;
    text-align: left;
}

.request-details h2 {
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: left;
}

.status-button {
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    .status-button {
        width: auto;
        padding-right: 20px;
        padding-left: 100px;
    }
}

.request-button {
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: 600;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    background-size: 150% auto;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(141,227,227,1) 0%, rgba(114,240,218,1) 100%);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.request-button:hover {
    background: #2de1c2;
}
```

The page looks like the following:

[image]

However, when the width of the screen decreases, I get the following:

[image]

The right edge of the boxes gets cut off, and the width of the boxes does not get smaller in size in response to the width of the screen decreasing.

I am not sure how to resolve this issue. Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: .request-box  max-width: 100%;

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `.request-box` to have only top&bottom margin, and add right/left padding on the container (`.request-list`).

Check this:

```css
request.css:

.requests-container {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    grid-row-gap: 30px;
}

.request-box {
    border: 1px solid #c3c9c8;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #ededed;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.request-details {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0 30px;
    height: 100%;
}

.request-details h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #28bfa6;
    text-align: left;
}

.request-details h2 {
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: left;
}

.status-button {
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    .status-button {
        width: auto;
        padding-right: 20px;
        padding-left: 100px;
    }
}

.request-button {
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: 600;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    background-size: 150% auto;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(141,227,227,1) 0%, rgba(114,240,218,1) 100%);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.request-button:hover {
    background: #2de1c2;
}
.request-list {
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Requests Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="requestnew.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="requests-page">
        <h1>Requests</h1>
        <div class="requests-container">
            <div class="request-list">
                <div class="request-box">
                    <div class="request-details">
                        <div>
                            <h1>Table 9, 12:00PM</h1>
                            <h2>Need help with ordering</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="status-button">
                            <button type="button" class="request-button">Assistance Requested</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="request-box">
                    <div class="request-details">
                        <div>
                            <h1>Table 9, 12:00PM</h1>
                            <h2>Need help with ordering</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="status-button">
                            <button type="button" class="request-button">Assistance Requested</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="request-box">
                    <div class="request-details">
                        <div>
                            <h1>Table 9, 12:00PM</h1>
                            <h2>Need help with ordering</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="status-button">
                            <button type="button" class="request-button">Assistance Requested</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="request-box">
                    <div class="request-details">
                        <div>
                            <h1>Table 9, 12:00PM</h1>
                            <h2>Need help with ordering</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="status-button">
                            <button type="button" class="request-button">Assistance Requested</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The 100% width of your `.request-box` elements will *not*  include the 2 x 10px left and right `margin`, so this results in a width including margins of 100% PLUS 20px.

To avoid that, you can use  `width: calc(100% - 20px);` on `.request-box`, which will subtract the 20px left/right margin from the element width:

```css
.requests-container {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  grid-row-gap: 30px;
}

.request-box {
  border: 1px solid #c3c9c8;
  height: 200px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #ededed;
  margin: 10px;
}

.request-details {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 30px;
  height: 100%;
}

.request-details h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #28bfa6;
  text-align: left;
}

.request-details h2 {
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: left;
}

.status-button {
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .status-button {
    width: auto;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 100px;
  }
}

.request-button {
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background-size: 150% auto;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(141, 227, 227, 1) 0%, rgba(114, 240, 218, 1) 100%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.request-button:hover {
  background: #2de1c2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Requests Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="requestnew.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="requests-page">
    <h1>Requests</h1>
    <div class="requests-container">
      <div class="request-list">
        <div class="request-box">
          <div class="request-details">
            <div>
              <h1>Table 9, 12:00PM</h1>
              <h2>Need help with ordering</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="status-button">
              <button type="button" class="request-button">Assistance Requested</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="request-box">
          <div class="request-details">
            <div>
              <h1>Table 9, 12:00PM</h1>
              <h2>Need help with ordering</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="status-button">
              <button type="button" class="request-button">Assistance Requested</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="request-box">
          <div class="request-details">
            <div>
              <h1>Table 9, 12:00PM</h1>
              <h2>Need help with ordering</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="status-button">
              <button type="button" class="request-button">Assistance Requested</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="request-box">
          <div class="request-details">
            <div>
              <h1>Table 9, 12:00PM</h1>
              <h2>Need help with ordering</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="status-button">
              <button type="button" class="request-button">Assistance Requested</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```